# Why I can't block PING.EXE inbound and outbound traffic?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, firewall, ping

I want to block `C:\Windows\System32\ping.exe` for any inbound or outbound traffic in Windows-7. So in the Windows Firewall, I added two rules to aim this goal (one for inbound and one another for outbound traffic).

Firewall is On. but still I can `ping` others and others can `ping` my computer. Why?

The Firewall configuration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note that** I know I can block `ICMP` protocol instead, but I don't want to block it in that way. I just want to block this program.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the firewall rules you added.

Comment: @DavidPostill Added. Tnx

Comment: Note that since ping.exe doesn't listen on any ports and the kernel is what responds to ICMP traffic, you cannot block incoming pings by blocking the instance of ping.exe on your computer. It would be kind of like trying to block people from viewing a web server on your computer by blocking incoming traffic to Internet Explorer.

Comment: Why? Do you have any valid reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I allow or block Ping Response in Windows?

Blocking `ping.exe` will not stop inbound ping responses as they are are handled at a lower level by the operating system.

`ping.exe` is used to make outbound ping requests.

Instead you need to block the Ping **Port** and **Protocol** (both inbound and outbound in your case.

> 1. Press the WIN key, type "windows firewall" and run it.
> 2. Click on "Advanced settings" located at the left hand sidebar.
> 3. Click on "Inbound Rules" at the left pane.
> 4. Click "Action" from the menu bar and select "New Rule".
>
> [image]
>
> 5. Click on "Custom" and click "Next".
> 6. Make sure the "All programs" option is selected and click "Next".
> 7. Click on the "Protocol type" drop down menu, select "ICMPv4" and click "Next".
>
> [image]
>
> 8. Make sure both "Any IP address" is selected and click "Next".
> 9. If you want to enable ping when you are connected to a public network, select "Allow the connection". If you want to block ping even
>      when you are connected to home network, select "Block the connection"
>      option and click "Next".
>
> [image]
>
> 10. You can leave all the checkboxes ticked for the profiles and click "Next".
> 11. Give this new rule any name you like, for example "block ping" or "allow ping" and click "Finish".
>
>     The newly created firewall rule will take effect instantly without
>       requiring a reboot.
>
> Additional Note:
>
> In the Windows operating system, selecting your network location as
>   Home or Work will allow ping while the Public network profile will
>   block ping. The above Windows Firewall rule will override the network
>   location rule.

Source [4 Ways to Allow or Block Ping Response in Windows](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/blocking-ping-response-in-windows-to-prevent-hackers-from-finding-you/)

Comment: Thank you dear David. So, as `ping.exe` doesn't listen any port or send any packet, blocking it doesn't change anything. it only send a request to OS to send an `ICMP` packet to a target, right?

Comment: This doesn't actually really answer the question, though (in fact, OP specifically said they didn't want to just block ICMP...). So... why doesn't blocking ping.exe at the firewall prevent you from using it to send outgoing pings? Its traffic doesn't show up in the Resource Monitor either.

Comment: What about `telnet.exe` program. Adding rules for this file, must prevent other computers to connect to my computer with telnet command, because this file send and receive packets and listen to ports itself,  right?

Comment: @Abraham Basically that is correct.

Comment: `telnet` and `telnetd` are the standard names for the client and server of the telnet protocol. Telnet clients (`telnet.exe`) do not listen on any port. That would be the telent *server*, usually called `telnetd`, at least on Unix-like systems.

Comment: @CBHacking "OP specifically said they didn't want to just block ICMP" was added in an edit. It was not in his original question. This answer **does** answer his **original** question.

Comment: @CBHacking ICMP traffic is not shown in the resource monitor (which shows TCP traffic).  ICMP (which is what ping uses) is implemented directly on top of IP packets and doesn't use a transport layer (OSI layer 4) like TCP or UDP.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm familiar with TCP and ICMP and so on, but didn't realize Resource Monitor only showed TCP (pretty sure it shows UDP as well, but yeah, not ICMP and probably not a bunch of other protocols either).